# Meaning of dreams with some kinds of animals

Tags: animals, symbols-symbology, tractate-brachot, dream

The gemara in berachot says: "All kinds of beasts are a good sign in a dream, except the elephant, the monkey and the long-tailed ape" (57b).
Why is a dream with an elephant, a monkey or a long-tailed ape not a good sign? Does this sentence of the gemara mean that a dream with one of those animals is a *bad* sign?

Comment: Starving cows don't seem to be so good either. :-)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1847/759

Comment: is related...but doesn't really answer...

Comment: @MonicaCellio Starving cows are good for reuniting families...